# Disable ads in Viber

Tags: windows, advertisements, viber

Recent version of Viber on Windows started displaying ads. It appeared in sidebar under contacts. There is no GUI option to disable.

How can I disable them?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1477874/remove-ads-in-viber-for-pc

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I put

```
127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads.aws.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads-d.viber.com
127.0.0.1 s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
```

into my c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file. Since then I have no ads ;) Hope it'll help for you, too.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tested, but I hope this works.

Comment: Let me know if you have tested!

Comment: Confirming that it works.

Comment: Also works on macOS. File `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Same on Linux: /etc/hosts

Comment: bless you kind person

Comment: Live long and prosper!

Comment: for linux/mac run: 
sudo echo 127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com >> /etc/hosts

Comment: Still works as of writing this.

Comment: Viber should thank you and put you on the payroll. I was about to uninstall.

Comment: @Miro: same :). They have no idea how much the BAD kid of ads harm them. If the ads were more gentle and not long, cpu-hogging videos more people would probably use their software. *sigh*

Comment: God bless you!!!

Comment: This no longer works after a recent Viber update.

Comment: New url added to prevent ads in the new Viber 11.4.0 ;)

Comment: Ads are back after the latest Viber update, 11.9.1 .

Comment: block *.adnxs.com. Specifically fra1-ib.adnxs.com, mediation.adnxs.com, ams1-mobile.adnxs.com and crcdn01.adnxs.com. Personally I blocked everything from adnxs.com

Comment: @Panagiotis Thank you! It works.

Answer (score 12):

I had to block extra addresses (discovered in Proxifier):

```
ads.cdn.viber.com
ads.*.viber.com
locp-ir.viber.com
```

Also I had to open preferences and close. Then the effect was achieved.

Comment: Thank you. The ads were back but thanks to these additional addresses managed to get rid of them again. ARGH, nevermind, they're back again. What software did you use to find the addresses? Wireshark is sometimes a bit too verbose.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks you wise sir!

Comment: @Axonn I used [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com)

Answer (score 4):

Owners of MikroTik routers who use DNS caching can create a static DNS entry on the router with **Regexp** field containing `ads(\-d|\.aws)?\.viber\.com` and **Address** field containing `127.0.0.1`. That will stop all devices on the network (phones, tablets) from showing those ads, not just a single PC or Mac computer like with the `hosts` file.

Owners of Ubiquiti EdgeRouter devices can do the same but will have to create three separate entries because EdgeRouter does not support regex. Same goes for any other router or firewall, better to block on the edge.