# Remove ads in Viber for PC

Tags: hosts, advertisements, viber

How do I disable ads in Viber for PC - version 11.4 (2019). The hosts file trick no longer works (the following one):

```
127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads.aws.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads-d.viber.com
```

Viber offers no option to disable (paid) ads and their ads are too large and too disruptive (covering half of the contact list).

Comment: OP notes previous solutions no longer work. Unless someone can verify that they do, this is NOT a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1230742/disable-ads-in-viber

Comment: Are you certain that those addresses are the only ones being used?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 images.taboola.com` for kill current image. Ads still here but white.

Comment: @music2myear rest assured it is does not work with the above list and it is not a duplicate - in fact, most questions of this kind are a year or two old and refer only ads.viber.com which used to be sufficient for the above purpose. I'll try the rest of the list and report back.

Comment: For the moment the list from @ZoltánKurgya works, we'll see how it behaves after a while.

Comment: You are aware that this is probably a violation of their terms of conditions of use, and that you are actually stealing a service from them by doing so? If you don't want the ads, find an alternative.

Comment: @Coder12345 that is exactly what I said.

Comment: @jcaron SE as a whole apparently does not care, even with this question being featured on the hot network questions for quite some time. BTW yes, you are right, it's violating their TOS and this question and answers are encouraging that, which pretty much violates SE's own TOS. But hey, it's 2019 and not 2009 anymore ... Moderation is limited to deleting comments, making 100 page meta discussions and flagging for duplicates for half a decade now.

Comment: @jcaron Apparently, I have determined that there is a suspicious traffic coming from those URLs and I am blocking them to safeguard my own system, and saving bandwidth. So not violating SE own TOS. I wouldn't know if I am violating Viber's TOS. I pay random people on the street to click "I Agree" buttons for me.

Comment: I am closing this as it is against the (spirit of) the terms of service in that you shouldn't be trying to circumvent or otherwise abuse specific programs or copyright holders. A *slightly* more generic question of "Given a nonspecific program, how do I determine what sites it connects to?" Might well be on topic as it can be viewed as a general system protection question. We all hate adverts, but sometimes developers go for a small evil for the greater good (free). Adverts are near the point where they are considered harmful, but I don't think we should single out sites or programs.

Comment: This is one of those difficult to judge questions that may merit discussion on [meta].

Comment: @Coder12345 a last point, ignorance of the law (paying someone else to agree to the terms of service) does not absolve you of responsibility or liability to those laws or terms of service. I'm not advocating one way or another about the ad-blocking (I do use an ad-blocker in general but disable it for sites I use regularly) but in general if you were to be arrested for something *actually* illegal such as theft or murder, then saying "I didn't know it was illegal officer" is likely to be given short shrift.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I put also these two into my "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" file:
(for mac the file location is: "/private/etc/hosts"), however, as others may suggest, later on new ad sites filtering might need.

```
127.0.0.1 rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
...
```

so I have these now: (Viber related)

```
127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads.aws.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads-d.viber.com
127.0.0.1 rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 ams1-mobile.adnxs.com
127.0.0.1 api.mixpanel.com
127.0.0.1 fra1-ib.adnxs.com
127.0.0.1 mediation.adnxs.com
```

Comment: After some time this was not enough as new domains are added. Here is my list i managed to collect so far:

`127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads.aws.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads-d.viber.com
127.0.0.1 s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 ams1-mobile.adnxs.com
127.0.0.1 api.mixpanel.com
127.0.0.1 fra1-ib.adnxs.com
127.0.0.1 mediation.adnxs.com`

Comment: @OgnjenBabic - Thanks Mate, added your suggestion to the list.

Answer (score 9):

```
127.0.0.1 images.taboola.com
127.0.0.1 api.taboola.com
```

Do the job.
First for kill image.
Second for kill load ads data from this ads network.
But if viber switch to other ads network, this solution stop work.
Or if it use another network for you.

I suggest install [DNSQuerySniffer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_query_sniffer.html) unload viber, run tool, run viber, and monitor your DNS queries.
If you see some suspicious DNS query - block it in hosts.

Comment: Thank you for the added URLs, but you should also clarify this makes the images white as well in the answer (which might prove useful as a backup solution if the above ones stop working in some later version).

Comment: @Coder12345 `api.taboola.com` block ads completely.

Answer (score 7):

After my investigation, here are my hosts items:

```
127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads.aws.viber.com
127.0.0.1 ads-d.viber.com
127.0.0.1 s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 s-imp.rmp.rakuten.com
127.0.0.1 api.mixpanel.com
```