Remove viber ads - PC
How can ads in desktop viber (windows pc) be disabled? After very long time viber started showing "sponsored" ads and when you click close it, a popup appears for viber plus/premium. Ads appear inside viber desktop application on windows, in viber sidebar under contacts
Previous way with hosts file doesnt work (have long list). Maybe a new "site" needs to be added but how can i find which one serves the ad?
Previous answers from this question dont seem to work anymore
Remove ads in Viber for PC
Also tried to pinpoint the dns calls but requests are too many. tried 2-3 additions to hosts files without success.
viber win application version is 24.3.3.0
ad shown  on windows viber application viber
closing ad a popup appears within viber for premium features
UPDATE: added these 2 urls into hosts file and for the time being seems to be blocking the sponsored ad
127.0.0.1 feed.avplayer.com
127.0.0.1 player.avplayer.com

Where? In what PC? In what software on that PC? Are these ads showing in a browser? Have you installed ad plugins like uBlock Origin (the only ad block plugin you should use)? Are the ads popping up over your PC screen even when you don't have a browser running?

viber has windows pc application that you can send msg or make a call through pc. thats where the ads appear. Inside windows viber application. This has nothing to do with browser or the whole pc . similar closed question can be found here https://superuser.com/questions/1477874/remove-ads-in-viber-for-pc but its solution doesnt work for me now

Perhaps adding that info to the question would make it a bit more clear. Use the EDIT button to do that, especially the parts about making it clear you're talking about an application, and the list of things you've already tried.

added more details. is it ok now?
